# NHibernate connexion fail because of mapping file

Tags: c#, wpf, nhibernate, mvvm, mapping

I am working on an application that using NHibernate and MVVM. I am trying to add a new mapping file to my project but now the application can't open connexion with NHibernate (everything was working well before).

Note that I do not currently use the service related to the new mapping file

Mysql Table code (of the new mapping file)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Formats
(idFormat INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,idProduit  INT
,idUnite INT
,quantite INT
);
```

code class in the project :

```
public class Format : ObservableObject
{
    #region Membres privées
    private int? _idFormat = null;
    private Produit _produit;
    private Unite _unite;
    private int? _quantite;
    #endregion

    #region Propriétés

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets and gets the IdFormat property.
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// </summary>
    public virtual int? IdFormat
    {
        get
        {
            return _idFormat;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_idFormat == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            RaisePropertyChanging();
            _idFormat = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets and gets the Produit property.
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Produit Produit
    {
        get
        {
            return _produit;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_produit == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            RaisePropertyChanging();
            _produit = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets and gets the Unite property.
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Unite Unite
    {
        get
        {
            return _unite;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_unite == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            RaisePropertyChanging();
            _unite = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets and gets the Quantite property.
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// </summary>
    public int? Quantite
    {
        get
        {
            return _quantite;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_quantite == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            RaisePropertyChanging();
            _quantite = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Service :

```
public interface IFormatService
{
    IList<Format> RetrieveAll();
}
```

NHibernate Service :

```
public class NHibernateFormatService : IFormatService
{
    public IList<Format> RetrieveAll()
    {
        using (var session = NHibernateConnection.OpenSession())
        {
            return session.Query<Format>().ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Mapping (Embedded Resource) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping assembly="Econo.Bouffe"
                   namespace="Econo.Bouffe.Model"
                   xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="Format" table="Formats">
    <id name="IdFormat">
      <column name="idFormat" not-null="true" sql-type="INTEGER" />
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="Produits" class="Produit" lazy="false">
      <column name="idProduit" not-null="true" sql-type="INTERGER" />
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one name="Unites" class="Unite" lazy="false">
      <column name="idUnite" not-null="true" sql-type="INTERGER" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="Quantite">
      <column name="quantite" not-null="true" sql-type="INTERGER" />
    </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When I remove the .hbm.xml mapping file everything working fine but when I add it, I am getting this error :

```
An exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Econo.Bouffe.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The type initializer for 'Econo.Bouffe.Helpers.NHibernate.NHibernateConnection' threw an exception.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

at this line of code of another NHibernate Service:

```
using (var session = NHibernateConnection.OpenSession())
```

Comment: Its been a while since I used NHibernate but did you turn on profiling to the immediate window. That is definitely a help troubleshooting. Hibernating Rhinos and http://www.deftindustries.com/miniprofiler-mvc-and-nhibernate have some good tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your `class Format` in the above snippet is copy/pasted from your *real* code. If this is the case, the problem is the `public int? Quantite`, which is not **virtual**. Change your entity like this:

```
// virtual is a key to success
public virtual int? Quantite
{
    get {...
```

Expecting that you do have mapping for other entities *(Produits,...)* this should solve the issue

Comment: Thank you, I should buy some glass, I think I am really blind

Comment: Great if that helped. Enjoy NHibernate.